# Adding elevated permissions to scripts in a directory

Tags: linux, permissions, sudoers

I have a directory containing some scripts which I need to invoke from a web request. The scripts need elevated permissions to run.

My current thinking is to add the following lines to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Cmnd_Alias WEB_COMMANDS = /path/to/scripts
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: WEB_COMMANDS
```

Is this the correct approach to this problem? Or am I causing a potential security vulnerability?

Using CentOS 7, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything is a potential security vulnerability. Two things:

First of all, are you *sure* it needs root? Why? Can you do that with capabilities instead? (You probably can.)

That being said, your example is almost spot-on. Add an asterisk after the path:

```
Cmnd_Alias WEB_COMMANDS = /path/to/scripts/*
```

And now it will work. But beware, if any of those scripts can be modified by an attacker, the attacker gains **FULL ROOT ACCESS**. They can simply `exec('/bin/bash')` and have a shell. Definitely go the capabilities route per script if possible, and DEFINITELY lock down the script directory either way. See [this unix.se answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87371/78518) for info on managing capabilities with scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The library these scripts need to talk to is adamant that elevated permissions are required. I will check the capabilities info though in case that does turn out to work. If not, would it be sufficient to set the scripts' owner to root and permissions to 755 to prevent anyone from modifying them?

Comment: Tried upvoting your answer but can't do so with less than 15 reputation :-)

Comment: @SamHastings I'd say 755 is too open. Consider everything those scripts do. Could it be problematic if it were run when they weren't supposed to? I'd say unless you know you need more open access, 0700. I typically will do 0775 or 0770, but when I'm dealing with passwordless sudo I tend to be extra paranoid.